# How to show Recent Page instead of Post?

Tags: plugins, customization

I'm designing a WordPress website and would like to show up the pages that were created finally(much like the recent posts)

So, how can I modify the "Recent Posts" feature to show up Pages and not Posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a ready made custom widget for `recent page` it was made for `recent posts` .. So please change the post text to page in the below code.

> View thoroughly , only change the text that is for display purpose.

1. Add this code to your functions.php file
2. Goto appearance->widgets you will see you newly created widget `Custom Recent Pages`
3. Drag it to the active sidebar and make the changes as per requirement.
4. Done !!! you can see that in the front-end sidebar.

   ```
   add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_widgets_func' );

   class cust_recentpage_widget extends WP_Widget {


     function __construct() {

       parent::__construct(

         'cust_recentpage_widget', // Base ID

         __( 'Custom Recent Pages', 'text_domain' ), // Name

         array( 'description' => __( 'A Widget to display Recent Pages In the Website', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args

       );

     }

     public function widget( $args, $instance ) {



       if($instance['only_title'] == ''){

         //echo $args['before_widget'];

         echo '<aside class="col-md-4 block">';

         if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {

           echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];

         }



         if($instance['no_of_post'] == 0 || $instance['no_of_post'] == ''){

           $num_of_post = 3;

         } else{

           $num_of_post = $instance['no_of_post'];

         }

             // The Query

             $args = array(

                 'post_type'     => 'page',

                 'post_status'   => 'publish',

                 'posts_per_page'=> $num_of_post,

                 'orderby'       => 'ID',

                 'order'         => 'DESC'

                 );

             //p($args);

             $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );



             // The Loop

             if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                 $loop = '<ul class="data">';

                 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                     $the_query->the_post();

                     $strip_c  = strip_tags(get_the_content());



                         $loop .='<li class="press-box no-list-icon">';

                         if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                           $padd_left = '';

                           $strlimit = 70;

                           $loop .= '<div class="img">'.get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(),array(78,60)).'</div>';

                       }else{
                         $padd_left = 'style="padding-left: 0;"';

                         $strlimit = 80;

                       }

                       $content  =  substr($strip_c,0,$strlimit);

                       if(strlen(get_the_title()) > 25){

                             $tittle = substr(get_the_title(),0,26).'...';

                           }else{

                             $tittle = get_the_title();

                           }

                         $loop .= '<div class="details" '.$padd_left.'>

                                     <h5 title="'.get_the_title().'">'.$tittle.'</h5>

                                     <p>'.$content.'...</p>

                                 </div>

                             </li>';

                 }

                 $loop .='</ul>';

             } else {

                 $loop = 'No pages Yet';

             }

         /* Restore original Post Data */

         echo $loop;

         echo '</aside>';

       } else{

         //echo $args['before_widget'];

         echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';

         if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {

           echo $args['before_title'] .'<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="collapsed">'. apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). '</a>' .$args['after_title'];

         }



         $num_of_post = $instance['no_of_post'];

         if($num_of_post == ''){

           $num_of_post = 3;

         }

         // The Query

             $args = array(

                 'post_type'     => 'page',

                 'post_status'   => 'publish',

                 'posts_per_page'=> $num_of_post,

                 'orderby'       => 'ID',

                 'order'         => 'DESC'

                 );

             $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

         ?>

         <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">

             <div class="panel-body">

               <div class="links">

                 <?php 

                     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                     $the_query->the_post();

               ?>

                   <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>"><?php 

                   if(strlen(get_the_title()) > 15) {

                     echo substr(get_the_title(),0,16).'...';

                   } else{

                     echo get_the_title();

                   }?></a>

                   <?php 

                   } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

               </div>

             </div>

           </div>

           <?php 

           echo '</div>';

           //echo $args['after_widget'];

       }

     }


     public function form( $instance ) {

       $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Recent Posts', 'text_domain' );

       ?>

       <p>

       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Header Title:' ); ?></label> 

       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">

       </p>

       <?php 

       $no_of_post = ! empty( $instance['no_of_post'] ) ? $instance['no_of_post'] : __( '3', 'text_domain' );

       ?>

       <p>

       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'no_of_post' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of Posts:' ); ?></label> 

       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'no_of_post' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'no_of_post' ); ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $no_of_post ); ?>">

       </p>

       <?php 

       $checked = ! empty( $instance['only_title'] ) ? 1 : 0;

       if($checked == 1)

         $check_me = 'checked="checked"';

       else

         $check_me = '';

       ?>

       <p>

       <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'only_title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show in sidebar in Community News Page as Toggled Slider:' ); ?></label> 

       <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'only_title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'only_title' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php echo esc_attr( $check_me );?> >

       </p>



       <?php 

     }



     public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

       $instance = array();

       $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

       $instance['no_of_post'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['no_of_post'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['no_of_post'] ) : '';

       $instance['only_title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['only_title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['only_title'] ) : '';



       return $instance;

     }
   }?>
   ```